# Diferenças entre Monolito e Monorepo

Tags: front-end

Já li alguns artigos sobre Monorepo e ainda não entendi qual seria a diferença entre Monolito e Monorepo.

Alguém saberia me explicar?

Comment: Tambem sou leigo, mas sendo simplista acredito que monolito(ou monolítico) é o inverso de microserviços. Um backend `monolito` por exemplo, utiliza de uma arquitetura onde toda a estrutura do sistema (login, consultas, armazenamentos...) fica em um único código, usando uma linguagem como `C#`, `Java`, etc.... O `microserviço`, baseia-se no conceito de segmentar as funcionalidades onde , por exemplo, o login é um tipo de código e a consulta do perfil é outro tipo de código, e cada um usa a linguagem mais favorável para o seu tipo de serviço.

Comment: Acredito que o termo monorepo é o conceito de usar-se um único repositório para armazenar dezenas de microserviços, ao invés de ficarem em repositórios separados.

Comment: São dois conceitos que eu acho extremamente estranho misturar na comparação. Como comparar "abelha" e "abacate": ambos são seres vivos e começam com as mesmas letras.

Comment: Você pode ter um ou mais monolitos em um monorepo. Eles não são comparáveis. Monolito diz respeito a forma como sua aplicação está estruturada, por exemplo, se sua aplicação é uma só para conectar ao banco, processar as informações e exibir as informações no cliente para o usuário, pode considerar isso de forma simplista um monolito. Já o monorepo diz respeito a forma como você gerencia os repositórios das suas aplicações, por exemplo, você pode ter um blog que tem uma arquitetura monolítica e ter um sistema que gerencia suas finanças que não possui uma arquitetura monolítica, se você ...

Comment: ... optar por gerenciar os dois projetos em um único repositório (no git por exemplo) isso também de forma simplista é um monorepo.

Os dois conceitos possuem diversas estratégias e são bem mais complexos do que expliquei, mas de forma prática e resumida seria isso