# O que é um monorepo? Quais são as suas vantagens e desvantagens?

Tags: arquitetura-de-software

O que é um *monorepo* (mono repositório) e quais problemas ele procura resolver?

- Quais são as vantagens?
- Quais são as desvantagens?

Comment: Deve sair algo melhor do que em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/440839/101.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

O Monorepo como o próprio nome diz, seria um único repositório para manter o código de diversos projetos.

Em um ambiente de trabalho, na qual há diversos projetos separados que são integrados, é comum os desenvolvedores precisarem criar mocks, ou precisar carregar diversos projetos para realizar algumas atividades simples.

Por exemplo: Você possui um projeto que é responsável por realizar o Login. Esse projeto está em 10 outros projetos. Foi encontrado uma vulnerabilidade nesse projeto de Login. Com um Monorepo o ajuste seria bem mais simples.

**Vantagens**:

- Com a utilização de Monorepo, os diversos projetos estarão em apenas um único git, isso ajudará na reutilização de código.
- Com Monorepo é mais simples fazer um build de todos os projetos que foram alterados.
- É mais simples manter um único estilo visual para os diversos projetos, visto que é possível ter um projeto em comum para lidar com css e imagens.
- A integração de um novo membro no time tende a ser algo mais rápido e tranquilo, pois o mesmo não precisará baixar e configurar diversos projetos separados.

**Desvantagens**:

- Criar a cultura de utilizar um único repositório.
- Com base no crescimento do projeto, ele se torna mais custoso para realizar o clone.
- Não há uma forma de criar segurança entre os projetos, todos os desenvolvedores podem trabalhar em todos os projetos.
- Dependendo do sistema de Git, é bom avaliar o tamanho máximo do histórico de arquivos permitido, para assegurar que utilizar um Monorepo não será algo custoso.

Para mais informações, recomendo as seguintes leituras:

https://github.com/joelparkerhenderson/monorepo_vs_polyrepo

https://nx.dev/angular/getting-started/why-nx

https://cacm.acm.org/magazines/2016/7/204032-why-google-stores-billions-of-lines-of-code-in-a-single-repository/fulltext

Answer (score 5):

Penso que usar um monorepo tem mais desvantagens do vantagens como mencionado neste artigo:
https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/monorepos

Desvantagens que na minha opinião anulam as vantagens, considerando grandes monorepo:

- Problemas de perfomance em caso de monorepos grandes
- Histórico de commits (linha de tempo) dificultam entendimento do que vem sendo alterado e do que afeta o que, afetando também resolução de problemas
- Maior dificuldade para controlar versão de forma individual (por projetos).
- Maior dificuldade para controle de deploy e merge entre Branches de outros ambientes, resultando no envio de código incompleto para Branches de produção ou homologação
- De certa forma o uso de tag não faz muito sentido a não ser para todos os projetos ao mesmo tempo
- Falta de controle de acesso por projeto
- Maior tempo para download do projeto

Answer (score -1):

Cada projeto pode ter seu próprio versionamento, seu próprio deploy.
Quando eu penso em monorepo, faz sentido pra mim quando ambos projetos compartilham do mesmo código, bibliotecas e etc.